# issue with importing dependencies while running Dataflow from google cloud composer

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm running Dataflow from google cloud composer, the dataflow script contains some non-standard dependencies like zeep, googleads.
which are required to be installed on dataflow worker nodes, so I packaged them with setup.py. when I try to run this in a dag, composer is validating the dataflow files and complaining about `No module names Zeep , googleads`. So I created pythonvirtualenvoperator and installed all the non standard dependencies required and tried to run the dataflow job and it still complained about inporting zeep and googleads.

Here is my codebase:

```
PULL_DATA = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id=PROCESS_TASK_ID,
    python_callable=execute_dataflow,
    op_kwargs={
        'main': 'main.py',
        'project': PROJECT,
        'temp_location': 'gs://bucket/temp',
        'setup_file': 'setup.py',
        'max_num_workers': 2,
        'output': 'gs://bucket/output',
        'project_id': PROJECT_ID},
    requirements=['google-cloud-storage==1.10.0', 'zeep==3.2.0',
                  'argparse==1.4.0', 'google-cloud-kms==0.2.1',
                  'googleads==15.0.2', 'dill'],
    python_version='2.7',
    use_dill=True,
    system_site_packages=True,
    on_failure_callback=on_failure_handler,
    on_success_callback=on_success_handler,
    dag='my-dag')
```

and my python callable code:

```
def execute_dataflow(**kwargs):
        import subprocess
        TEMPLATED_COMMAND = """
                          python main.py \
                                 --runner DataflowRunner \
                                 --project {project} \
                                 --region us-central1 \
                                 --temp_location {temp_location} \
                                 --setup_file {setup_file} \
                                 --output {output} \
                                 --project_id {project_id} 
                          """.format(**kwargs)
        process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', TEMPLATED_COMMAND])
        process.wait()
        return process.returncode
```

My main.py file

```
import zeep
import googleads

{Apache-beam-code to construct dataflow pipeline}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you call `subprocess` you are invoking a new bash shell outside the virtualenv, i.e. the virtualenv is not activated so those deps are not available. The VirtualEnvOperator already calls subprocess for you, and it also generates a script, and a cmd to call that script and a way to pass args to that python script. You could use that magic `virtualenv_string_args` global inside the dataflow entrypoint to programatically add `PipelineOptions` to the dataflow job, rather than passing CLI args. Start with https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L386

Comment: Davos, Thanks for elaborating this. can you please provide example that how can we use string_args in `PythonVirtualenvOperator`,  and how to read them in python callable? Bit confused with the documentation, it says type of string_args is list[str], and separator should be newline.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/afa06aefa5e0d70836bd11c0116ef3c1d2db4fc3/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L232

Comment: Actually I think the issue is the python you are calling, not the new shell. The airflow operator installs a virtualenv in a temp directory, and that is where the python executable should be called from. I wonder if it might work if the subprocess had the right environment variables for path or pythonpath that pointed to the temp dir virtualenv.

Comment: Agreed, the docs aren't clear. Inferred from the source: You pass a `list[str]` into the `string_args` parameter of `PythonVirtualenvOperator` and then in your python code, you magically have access to a global var called `virtualenv_string_args` which is also a list of strings. In between, it copies your original list to a newline delimited file, but then it reconstructs your code into a script reads that args file back in as a list. I honestly don't know why they mention that `separator should be newline` because it's an internal implementation detail, not part of the API.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f8dacae03340cb8423e37d7b053e7625a157f89e/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L414 it opens that newline args file, parses the lines, and populates list of strings `virtualenv_string_args`. On Line416 it _inlines_ your python code. 

It's convoluted, but then there's probably no other way to make it work. It uses `inspect.getsource()` on your callable in order to in-line your code. Your function is inline-able, but then, there is that call to subprocess to launch a new python, a world within a world, like that movie "inception" it makes my head hurt.

Comment: Also when I said "that is where the python executable should be called from" (the temp dir) you don't need to worry about it, the operator handles it for you.

Answer (score 0):

My job has a `requirements.txt`. Rather than using the `--setup_file` option as yours does, it specifies the following:

```
--requirements_file prod_requirements.txt
```

This tells DataFlow to install the libraries in `requirements.txt` prior to running the job.

Reference: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

Comment: The problem is not with running the dataflow job. 
To explain briefly, the client machine from where dataflow job get submitted is expected to have those non standard  dependencies installed in them. In my case client machine is composer instance which bydefault doesnt have those dependencies installed, so I'm using pythonvirenvoperator and creating a virenv on the composer instance and tried to submit the dataflow job from the newly created virenv.
But still job scheduling failed with `no module named (zeep  and google ads)`.

Comment: Ah, so the issue is on the Cloud Composer side, not the Dataflow side. I'm not familiar with Cloud Composer, so I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sample Dataflow pipeline script with `import googleads, zeep`, I set up a test Composer environment. The DAG is just as yours, and I get the same error.
Then I make a couple of changes, to make sure the dependencies can be found on the worker machines.

In the DAG, I use a plain `PythonOperator`, not a `PythonVirtualenvOperator`.
I have my dataflow pipeline and setup file (`main.py` and `setup.py`) [in a Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_storage_name_bucket), so Composer can find them.
The setup file has a list of requirements where I need to have e.g. zeep and googleads. I adapted a sample setup file from [here](https://github.com/tuanavu/google-dataflow-examples/blob/master/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py), changing this:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'google-cloud-storage==1.10.0', 'zeep==3.2.0',
'argparse==1.4.0', 'google-cloud-kms==0.2.1',
'googleads==15.0.2', 'dill'
    ]

setuptools.setup(
    name='Imports test',
    version='1',
    description='Imports test workflow package.',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    cmdclass={
        # Command class instantiated and run during pip install scenarios.
        'build': build,
        'CustomCommands': CustomCommands,
        }
    )
```

My DAG is

```
with models.DAG(  'composer_sample',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    PULL_DATA = PythonOperator(
    task_id='PULL_DATA',
    python_callable=execute_dataflow,
    op_kwargs={
        'main': '/home/airflow/gcs/data/main.py',
        'project': PROJECT,
        'temp_location': 'gs://dataflow-imports-test/temp',
        'setup_file': '/home/airflow/gcs/data/setup.py',
        'max_num_workers': 2,
        'output': 'gs://dataflow-imports-test/output',
        'project_id': PROJECT_ID})
    PULL_DATA
```

with no changes to the Python callable. However, with this configuration I still get the error.

[Next step](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package), in the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) console, I go to "Composer" through the navigation menu, and then click on the environment's name. On the tab "PyPI packages", I add zeep and googleads, and click "submit". It takes a while to update the environment, but it works.

After this step, my pipeline is able to import the dependencies and run successfully. I also tried running the DAG with the dependencies indicated on the GCP console but not in the requirements of `setup.py`. And the workflow breaks again, but in different places. So make sure to do indicate them in both places.

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the libraries in your Cloud Composer environment (check out [this link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies)). There is a way to do it within the console but I find these steps easier:

1. Open your [environments page](https://console.cloud.google.com/composer/environments)
2. Select the actual environment where your Composer is running
3. Navigate to the *PyPI Packages* tab
4. Click edit
5. Manually add each line of your `requirements.txt`
6. Save

You might get an error if the version you provided for a library is too old, so check the logs and update the numbers, as needed.